# ubuntu does not show its GUI interface after installing virtualbox-guest-x11

Tags: graphics, virtualbox, xorg, virtualization

I am trying to use my Ubuntu on windows Virtualbox. With reference to this page (http://lifehacker.com/how-to-dual-boot-and-virtualize-the-same-partition-on-y-493223329), I managed to boot up Ubuntu as a guest OS on my Virtualbox.

Then I wanted to change the resolution of the screen, so I installed virtualbox-guest-x11 using apt-get install.

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-x11
```

After this, I tried to restart the machine, but ubuntu would not show it's GUI interface. After I choose Ubuntu on the GRUB bootloader, the screen goes black/purple. At first I thought it did not boot at all, but I was able to log in on command prompt by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F3. It's just the GUI that is not loading.

```
sudo service lightdm start
```

returns

> start: Job failed to start

I removed the package I installed for the last time, but the problem has not been fixed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Try one of this:**

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to launch the GUI interface
From the terminal change your desired resolution with:
`xrandr -s 1024x768` where *1024x768* is your desired resolution and reboot the system by:
`sudo reboot`
Waiting for your response.

Comment: "Can't open display" it says when I use xrandr command.

Answer (score 0):

A colleague and I have had same problem after apt-get upgrade updated the virtualbox-guest-utils and virtualbox-guest-x11 packages to version: 5.1.34-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.2. We reverted to version: 5.0.18-dfsg-2build1 and the problem went away. We have added the following to /etc/apt/preferences to block this version of the package:

```
# Block the following package versions from being installed
Package: virtualbox-guest-x11
Pin: version 5.1.34-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.2
Pin-Priority: -1

Package: virtualbox-guest-utils
Pin: version 5.1.34-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.2
Pin-Priority: -1
```

System: VirtualBox 5.2.8 on Windows 10 host, running Ubuntu 16.04 guest with kernel 4.4.0-116-generic

Answer (score 0):

I confirm this bug with Ubuntu 16.04 (host) and all my VMs (ubuntu 16.04). Impossible to start "x11".

I rebuild all on my host (purge/clean/install). On VMs, reverted to version 5.0.18-dfsg-2build fixed problem.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Thank you for pitching in to help! For those less technically savvy than you, would you be so kind as to [edit] your post to include the details on how to do what you did that solved the problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

the same kind of issue I was facing, in my case none of the **display managers** (it is used to provide graphical logins and handle authentication) service was running, I fixed it by starting gdm3(GNOME Display Manager).

```
sudo service gdm3 start
```

if it is not installed then you can install it by using

```
sudo apt-get install gdm3
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue, and firing `startx` in the terminal worked for me.

Hope it helps.